# CONTEXT INIT ERROR when making sparkSQL context with sparkjobserver

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, spark-jobserver

when I run 
`curl -d "" 'localhost:8090/contexts/test-context?num-cpu-cores=4&memory-per-node=512m'`
 it makes sparkContext with no problem but when I want to make a sparkSQL context I get an error I used this line to make it `curl -d "" '127.0.0.1:8090/contexts/sql-context?context-factory=spark.jobserver.context.SQLContextFactory'`
  here is the response it gives
`{
  "status": "CONTEXT INIT ERROR",
  "result": {
    "message": "",
    "errorClass": "java.lang.ClassNotFoundException",
    "stack": ["java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)", "java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)", "java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)", "java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)", "java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)", "java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)", "spark.jobserver.JobManagerActor.createContextFromConfig(JobManagerActor.scala:265)", "spark.jobserver.JobManagerActor$$anonfun$wrappedReceive$1.applyOrElse(JobManagerActor.scala:106)", "scala.runtime.AbstractPartialFunction$mcVL$sp.apply$mcVL$sp(AbstractPartialFunction.scala:33)", "scala.runtime.AbstractPartialFunction$mcVL$sp.apply(AbstractPartialFunction.scala:33)", "scala.runtime.AbstractPartialFunction$mcVL$sp.apply(AbstractPartialFunction.scala:25)", "ooyala.common.akka.ActorStack$$anonfun$receive$1.applyOrElse(ActorStack.scala:33)", "scala.runtime.AbstractPartialFunction$mcVL$sp.apply$mcVL$sp(AbstractPartialFunction.scala:33)", "scala.runtime.AbstractPartialFunction$mcVL$sp.apply(AbstractPartialFunction.scala:33)", "scala.runtime.AbstractPartialFunction$mcVL$sp.apply(AbstractPartialFunction.scala:25)", "ooyala.common.akka.Slf4jLogging$$anonfun$receive$1$$anonfun$applyOrElse$1.apply$mcV$sp(Slf4jLogging.scala:26)", "ooyala.common.akka.Slf4jLogging$class.ooyala$common$akka$Slf4jLogging$$withAkkaSourceLogging(Slf4jLogging.scala:35)", "ooyala.common.akka.Slf4jLogging$$anonfun$receive$1.applyOrElse(Slf4jLogging.scala:25)", "scala.runtime.AbstractPartialFunction$mcVL$sp.apply$mcVL$sp(AbstractPartialFunction.scala:33)", "scala.runtime.AbstractPartialFunction$mcVL$sp.apply(AbstractPartialFunction.scala:33)", "scala.runtime.AbstractPartialFunction$mcVL$sp.apply(AbstractPartialFunction.scala:25)", "ooyala.common.akka.ActorMetrics$$anonfun$receive$1.applyOrElse(ActorMetrics.scala:24)", "akka.actor.Actor$class.aroundReceive(Actor.scala:465)", "ooyala.common.akka.InstrumentedActor.aroundReceive(InstrumentedActor.scala:8)", "akka.actor.ActorCell.receiveMessage(ActorCell.scala:516)", "akka.actor.ActorCell.invoke(ActorCell.scala:487)", "akka.dispatch.Mailbox.processMailbox(Mailbox.scala:238)", "akka.dispatch.Mailbox.run(Mailbox.scala:220)", "akka.dispatch.ForkJoinExecutorConfigurator$AkkaForkJoinTask.exec(AbstractDispatcher.scala:393)", "scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:260)", "scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1339)", "scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1979)", "scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:107)"]
  }`

the same thing happens if I use `HiveContextFactory` too , this error comes even if my curl is like this `curl -d "" '127.0.0.1:8090/contexts/sql-context?context-factory'`

Comment: لا مصب اون واتس اپ رو و داشتی بالاخره

Answer (score 0):

You should build your `spark-jobserver` with `spark-jobserver-extras`. You can do this with SBT:

```
$ sbt
> project job-server-extras
> assembly
```

So you should take `jar` from target directory of `job-server-extras` project and you will can use `spark.jobserver.context.SQLContextFactory` and `HiveContextFactory`.